# How to view the content of a file before it is written?

Tags: windows, debuggers

I've got a process that writes to a file (database). In process monitor I see `WriteFile`. After this I see the file is about to be either written or updated (offset:length).

How can I reveal the content that is about to be written or updated in this file using Ollydbg?
Is there a tutorial or something similar? And how to specify the function on Ollydbg?

In process monitor, I see `WriteFile`, but in Ollydbg, what is the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a look at [Woodmann](http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/) or [tuts4you](http://tuts4you.com/) if you need tutorials. And if you want to see what is writes you will have to have where the pointers are stored for the function in question.

This has a lot to do with calling conventions, [cdecl and stdcall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511096/cdecl-or-stdcall-on-windows) and knowing about them is important for this..

I am going to try to explain using the writeFile function.

### How does WriteFile Work

First we look at the WriteFile declaration (taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747(v=vs.85).aspx))

```
BOOL WINAPI WriteFile(
  _In_         HANDLE hFile,
  _In_         LPCVOID lpBuffer,
  _In_         DWORD nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
  _Out_opt_    LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
  _Inout_opt_  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

Now when we assume that Windows has stdcall (win32api has). We can figure out where we can find the variables. (for more about the stdcall see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall)).

Due to our wikipedia article we a few things:

- The parameters are pushed onto the stack in right-to-left order
- Registers EAX, ECX, and EDX are designated for use within the function.
- Return values are stored in the EAX register.
- stdcall is the standard calling convention for the Microsoft Win32 API.

### This is great

Now we have everything we need to figure out where we can find the location of the information you need.
When a breakpoint is placed on the function call you'll know that all the variables are stored on the stsck. LPCVOID is a Pointer, all that is left is to follow it and read the data.

Comment: really thanks for your efforts just two thinks to know 1- what u means the returned values are stored in EAx do u mean that this values will be used by writefile ? 
2-what is LPCVOID?

Comment: @studentofmp From one of the supplied links: If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero (TRUE).
So when the write is successful the eax register is non-zero.

Comment: i have set a breakpoint on the exact address just before the writefile function whene i hold "F8" to setp into ... in the process monitor "the writefile appears" but EAX = 0 where can i see the EAX value? thanks

Comment: thanks i have seen the full assci but now how can i edit this content before it will be written ? shoul be the last question